# Camera onPreviewFrame not called on XT910

Tags: android-camera, surfaceview

I have a problem with the camera of my MOTO XT910 android phone. I would like only to access to the camera's (frame)buffer but "onPreviewFrame" is never called. On my emulator, it works fine.

Thanks in advance,

My code is as below:

```
public class Store extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, PreviewCallback {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}

public native void decode(Bitmap pTarget, byte[] pSource);

private Camera mCamera;
private byte[] mVideoSource;
private Bitmap mBackBuffer;
private Paint mPaint;
private Size lSize;
private static String TAG = Store.class.getCanonicalName();


public Store(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated ok");
    } catch (IOException eIOException) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated failed");
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder pHolder, int pFormat, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged in");
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    lSize = findBestResolution(pWidth, pHeight);        
    invalidate();       
    PixelFormat lPixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
    PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(mCamera.getParameters()
            .getPreviewFormat(), lPixelFormat);
    int lSourceSize = lSize.width * lSize.height * lPixelFormat.bitsPerPixel / 8;
    mVideoSource = new byte[lSourceSize];
    mBackBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(lSize.width, lSize.height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Camera.Parameters lParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    lParameters.setPreviewSize(lSize.width, lSize.height);
    lParameters.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
    mCamera.setParameters(lParameters);
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged out");
}

private Size findBestResolution(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    List<Size> lSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Size lSelectedSize = mCamera.new Size(0, 0);
    for (Size lSize : lSizes) {
        if ((lSize.width <= pWidth) && (lSize.height <= pHeight)
                && (lSize.width >= lSelectedSize.width)
                && (lSize.height >= lSelectedSize.height)) {
            lSelectedSize = lSize;
        }
    }
    if ((lSelectedSize.width == 0) || (lSelectedSize.height == 0)) {
        lSelectedSize = lSizes.get(0);
    }
    return lSelectedSize;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceDestroyed");
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

        mCamera = null;
        mVideoSource = null;
        mBackBuffer = null;
    }
}

public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] pData, Camera pCamera) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onPreviewFrame");
    decode(mBackBuffer, pData);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas pCanvas) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onDraw in");
    if (mCamera != null) {
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
        String text = String.format("%dx%d", lSize.width, lSize.height);
        pCanvas.drawText(text, 10, 10, paint);          
        pCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
        pCanvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint); 
        pCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackBuffer, 0, 0, mPaint);

        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
        Log.d(TAG,"onDraw out");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

First I assume you didn't get an exception and that the camera parameters you used (PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP) is supported by your camera.

To fix the problem you should try to add mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(view);
with a surface view and not with null. Unfortunately according to android guys the preview should not start without a surface view :

> Unfortunately, there's no way to get preview frames without having a SurfaceView to display them, if you're targeting pre-3.0 devices. On 3.0 and later, you can use the Camera#setPreviewTexture() method to send preview data to a GPU texture. Even if just want to use the YUV data instead of RGB data in the GPU, this would allow you to stream without a mandatory UI element; just ignore the SurfaceTexture entirely.
>
> If you stick with your current approach, you'll unfortunately find that your app will not function properly on many devices; there are several that follow the API's restriction on having to have setPreviewDisplay() or setPreviewTexture() set before preview data will be sent.

See the full bug report here : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28238

However as I said in this bug report it can work without a surface view, but there is no guarantee.